# Why am I getting back "undefined" from my Axios call, when it should return me objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

**Problem Intro:**

In my React app I'm making some API calls to Github to fetch some user data. In another function I call these functions and wait for it with Axios's `.all()` method.

I want to fetch the data and do something with it using `.then()` but the returned value is just an array with 2 times undefined

**What is the expected thing to happen:**

It should return me 2 player objects with profile infos in the `profile` key of the object and a score value in the `score` key of the object.

**What is my app doing in a nutshell?**

It fetches the data from 2 usernames and they can "battle" each other. It just fetches the score and the followers and returns a sum. At the end it (should) returns an array with 2 player objects already sorted with the winner in the first place (`exampleArray[0]`).

**General information's**
It's an react app using components. It's really about one very tiny component and the helper functions in another file.

Here is where I call my custom function (the one returning undefined):

```
componentDidMount() {
    const players = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search); //<== the usernames
    const playersArray = [players.playerOneName, players.playerTwoName];
    console.log(playersArray); // <== this logs the output as expected (an array with 2 usernames)

    battle(playersArray).then((data) => {   // <== the function it's all about
        console.log(data); // <== data is => [undefined, undefined];
    })
}
```

Next is the battle function from above that uses 2 other functions:

**battle**

```
export function battle(players) { // <== players aray with 2 usernames as string
return axios.all(players.map(getUserData)) // <== look 1 function below
    .then(sortPlayers) // <== two functions below
    .catch(handleError)
}
```

**getUserData**

```
let getUserData = (player) => {
axios.all([
    getProfile(player),
    getRepos(player)
]).then((data) => {
    return {
        profile: data[0],
        score: calculateScore(data[0], data[1])
    }
})
}
```

**sortPlayers**

```
let sortPlayers = (players) => {

return players.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.score - a.score;
})
}
```

Ok so they also use other functions but they are really not too complicated. Let me know when you need examples from the other little helpers too.

I tried it with placing the debugger in different spots in the code and console logged different things, but I can't come through (first time I'm really working with promises). Sitting now 2 hours in front of this tiny problem and I can't figure it out.

I think the problem lies somewhere in battle function itself or `getUserData`

At the end a little screenshot, what the output of my console.log looks: http://prntscr.com/hz5abq

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to debug your callbacks to find out where the data gets lost. I get that you already did this but in order to solve this we'd have to basically build a copy. Actually, nevermind, `getUserData` isn't returning the `axios()`.

Comment: That kind sir fixed my problem. I don't know if should feel good or bad right now. Thx again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getUserData needs to return the promise that it creates. At the moment it's not returning anything, so an implicit undefined is returned, and thus `players.map(getUserData)` results in an array of `[undefined, undefined]`

Ie, do this:

```
let getUserData = (player) => {
    // VVV added return statement
    return axios.all([
        getProfile(player),
        getRepos(player)
    ]).then((data) => {
        return {
            profile: data[0],
            score: calculateScore(data[0], data[1])
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed my problem. Of course I overlooked something essential.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have anything being  returned in getUserData . Either add a `return` or remove the `{}` wrapping `axios.all`

```
let getUserData = (player) => {

    return axios.all([
        getProfile(player),
        getRepos(player)
    ]).then((data) => {
        return {
            profile: data[0],
            score: calculateScore(data[0], data[1])
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Hi thx that fixed my problem. I have a tiny question for you while you are here. Is it good or common practice on stackoverflow to comment every answer? It's no problem for me, but maybe it's not good to do this ? I'm pretty new to stack and I googled that but can't find anything :D
Thank you again!

Comment: No it's fine and welcomed. In this case i think you knew immediately what issue was but often there is a little back and forth on clarifications or tweaks if answer isn't quite what was expected

Comment: Thx again :) very appreciated.